# WordPress wp_email() not working in commandline

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to send an email in Wordpress plugin using wp_mail() function. The code is sending email when opened in a browser. I want to execute the file using a cron job. But when executing the file in command line I am getting the following error in the WordPress log file.

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [wp_mail_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid address:  (setFrom) wordpress@
                )

        )
```

Comment: `wordpress@` isn't a valid email. Is that the exact address it's trying to send to?

Comment: No. I am using a correct email and is working when running through the browser.